# How to retrieve id value from employee map props

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Below is the method which accepts a List of Employee objects, I need to pass id value of map obejct, which is inside employee object. I am new to Java8, pls look into below:

```
class Service {
     void meth(List<Employee> employees){
                employees.stream().flatMap(e -> map = e.getProps())
                .keySet().stream())     
                .filter(s -> s.equals("id"))         
                .allMatch(idValue -> isIdValid(empName, idValue).test(id)); //how to pass empName and  "id" Value here from employee map props object??
        }


      boolean isIdValid(String name, String id){
         //validation of id here
      }
    }


class Employee{
    String name;
    Map<String, Object> props;
}
```

Employee JSON

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "props": {
        "id": "123", //this value has to retreive
        "field2": "hey"
    }
}
```

I need to pass empName and "id" values in isIdValid method, how pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `entrySet` as:

```
return employees.stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getProps().entrySet().stream())
                .filter(s -> s.getKey().equals("id"))
                .allMatch(e -> isIdValid(idValue).test(e.getValue()));
```

---

*Edit*:- With the updated question , seems like you're looking for

```
return employees.stream()
        .filter(emp -> emp.getProps().containsKey("id"))
        .allMatch(emp -> isIdValid(emp.getName(),
                (String) emp.getProps().get("id")));
```

Comment: In above, can I use map, instead of flatMap?

Comment: how to write above one using map? instead of flatMap? just want to know..

Comment: I bit edited the question, please have a look, along with id, I need to pass emp name as well, how to do that?

Comment: @john just add `.filter(e -> e.getName().equals(name)` after `stream()`

Comment: @ginkul But how to pass empName  inside isIdValid method?

Comment: @john not sure if it's possible using Stream API

Comment: @john The code `allMatch(idValue -> isIdValid(empName, idValue).test(id))` doesn't make sense if `isIdValid` already returns `boolean` what is `.test(id)` for?